# Represent email, telephonenumber and id's as POJO's instead of Strings

Tags: java, string, oop

I have a typical business web application where the domain contains entities like accounts and users. My backend is Java, so they're represented by POJO's. During an early iteration, every attribute of those POJO's were just strings. This made sense because the html input was a string, and the way the data is persisted in the DB is also similar to a string.

Recently, we've been working on validating this kind of input and I found it helps if I switch over to an object notation for this kind attributes. For example, a `TelephoneNumber` class consists of:

- (int) country calling code
- (string) rest of number
- (static char) the character to prefix the country calling code (in our case this is a +)
- (static pattern) regular expression to match if phonenumber is sensical
- methods to compare and validate telephone numbers.

This class has advantages and disadvantages:

- not good: Additional object creation and conversion between string/object
- good: OOP and all logic regarding telephone numbers is bundled in one class (high cohesion),
- good: whenever a telephone number is needed as an argument for a method or constructor, java's strict typing makes it very clear we're not just dealing with a random string.

Compare the possible confusing double strings:

```
public User(String name, String telephoneNumber)
```

vs the clean OOP way:

```
public User(String name, TelephoneNumber telephoneNumber)
```

I think in this case the advantages outweight the disadvantges. My concern is now for the following two attributes:

-id's (like b3e99627-9754-4276-a527-0e9fb49d15bb)
-e-mailadresses

This "objects" are really just a single string. It seems overkill to turn them into objects. Especially the `user.getMail.getMailString()` kind of methods really bother me because I know the mailString is the only attribute of mail. However, if I don't turn them into an object, I lose some of the advantages.

So **my question** is: How do you deal with this concepts in a web application? Are there best practices or other concerns to take into account?

Comment: What conversions are you thinking with *conversion between string/object* ?

Comment: *This "objects" are really just a single string.* - your example includes structure and functions that don't exist in your string (or only exist implicitly) - there is value in what you want to do you have defined yourself, so it's worth doing. Creating objects isn't overkill in an object oriented language.

Comment: @Ascalonian Object o = new Object("string"); and everywhere in the code where it used to say user.getMail() it would become user.getMail.getMailString()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Strings for everything you are essentially giving up type safety, and you have to "type check" with validation in any class or method where the string is used. Inevitably this validation code gets duplicated and makes other classes bloated, confusing, and potentially inconsistent because the validation isn't the same in all places. You can never really be sure what the string holds, so debugging becomes more difficult, maintenance gets ugly, and ultimately it wastes lots of developer time. Given the power of modern processors, you shouldn't worry about the performance cost of using lots of objects because it's not worth sacrificing programmer productivity (in most cases).

One other thing that I have found is that string variables tend to be more easily abused by future programmers who need to make a "quick fix", so they'll set new values for convenience just where they need them, instead of extending a type and making it clear what's going on.

My recommendation is to use meaningful types everywhere possible.

Maximizing the benefit of typing leads to the idea of "tiny types", which you can read about here: http://darrenhobbs.com/2007/04/11/tiny-types/

Essentially it means you make classes to represent *everything*. In your example with the `User` class, that would mean you would also make a `Name` class to represent the name. Inside that class you might also have two more classes, `FirstName` and `LastName`. This adds clarity to your code, and maximizes the number of logical errors the compiler stops you from making. In most cases you would never use a first name where you want a last name and vice versa.

Comment: Excellent! I did not know this was called "tiny types". The article you linked you sums up nicely why I was hesitating: "most developers recoil at the thought, but ...".

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest advantages of objects is the fact that they can have methods.  For example, all your data object (phone number, address, email etc.) can implement the same interface `IValidatable` with `validate` method, which does the obvious.  In this case, it would make sense to wrap email in an object as well, since we do want to validate emails.  Regarding ID - assuming it's assigned internally by your app, you probably don't need to wrap it.

Comment: For me the biggest advantage of Email object instead of String is that it's much easier to add some additional fields in future. For example your apllication may need additional informations like boolean isValid, Locale country, boolean isCellPhone etc.